# What would tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: .none) to crash like this?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uikit

I’m trying to make sense of an error in Fabric:

> Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 0. The number of rows contained in an existing section after the update (40) must be equal to the number of rows contained in that section before the update (20), plus or minus the number of rows inserted or deleted from that section (1 inserted, 1 deleted) and plus or minus the number of rows moved into or out of that section (0 moved in, 0 moved out).
>   specialized NewInboxViewController.tableView(UITableView, didSelectRowAt : IndexPath)

Happens on this line in `didSelectRow:AtIndexPath`:

```
tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: .none)
```

The table view behavior is:

- view model loads 20 rows
- when the user scrolls to 70% of the table view, we load 20 more rows, an `isDownloading` bool is toggled to true, set to false when call finishes, then the table view reload
- `can commit edits` is false while `isDownloading` is true, otherwise the user can swipe to delete the row
- when the user pulls to refresh, we blow away whatever is stored in the array the cells are pulled from and replace with 20 recent items from the API call (edited)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are telling the table view to reload one row but you added 20 new rows to the data model. That's what the error means. It says:

> "before you called `reloadRows` there had been 20 rows in the data model. Now I see there are 40 rows in the data model but you are only telling me to reload (insert and delete) 1 row."

You should instead be calling `tableView.insertRows(at:)` with an array of 20 new index paths, one for each newly added row.

Comment: Thanks @rmaddy. It seems like this is a race condition where a `loadMore` operation is finishing at the same time that a user is selecting a conversation. The reason I'm reloading that single row is to update its style from unread to read. Since this is happening in `didSelectRow:atIndexPath`, somehow I need to figure out how to say, "did a bunch of new ones just load in? if so, do something special, otherwise, reload the row." Any suggestions?

Comment: You need to show relevant code to get more specific help. Edit your question showing where you add all the new rows and the code that needs to reload one row.

Comment: i think i can solve this by not doing the `reloadRows` if `viewModel.isDownloading == true`. since that fetch operation will refresh the table view and give the desired UI effect anyway. That should solve the race condition